# Putting text from one corner to the opposite one

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'd like my plot to have a background text to be stretched from one corner (say lower left) to the opposite corner. The x and y dimensions are not isometric and it's not a square plot, so a fixed angle of 45 degrees will not work.

So far I have the text starting in the correct corner. How can the text be rotated and stretched so it spans the entire plot?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# plot command not shown

ax.text(ax.get_xlim()[0], ax.get_ylim()[0] , 'PRELIMINARY' , rotation=45  )
```

Answer (score 1):

To position something with respect to the subplot (the `ax`), it helps to work in [axes coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html). These go from `0,0` in the lower left to `1,1` in the top right.  Putting the text at `0.5,0.5` would set it nicely centered.

To calculate the angle, one could divide the subplot's [height in pixels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_window_extent.html) by its width, then take the arc tangent, and convert from radians to degrees.

The optimal size for the text is harder to calculate. One would need to render it, measure it, change the font size and render it again. Or just manually try a few sizes until it looks OK.

Note that when the window size gets changed interactively, the text will stay nicely in the center, but the rotation will get a bit off.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'PRELIMINARY', transform=ax.transAxes, size=50,
        rotation=np.degrees(np.arctan(ax.get_window_extent().height / ax.get_window_extent().width)),
        ha='center', va='center')
plt.show()
```

[image: text from bottom left to top right]

Comment: Cool, that helps!

Comment: `> The optimal size for the text is harder to calculate. One would need to render it, measure it, change the font size and render it again.` If you will indulge me: I know this is the only way to do it. But do you happen to understand why? What ties the size of a text box to render coordinates when the fontsize is effectively in display coordinates?

Comment: Well, a text isn't stuffed into a box. It is carefully set letter per letter (given fontsize and dpi), needs to include [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) (distance between letters depends on the letter pair) and needs to include subpixel antialiasing (to make e.g. the 3 legs of an `m` look exactly the same. See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) for some brief introduction into the topic.

Comment: Does this solve the question enough? Or is programmatically fiddling with the fontsize (and leaving some padding?) necessary?